# MSSQL Performance - large n on JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

```
SELECT  A.Id, AMerge.FeildA, AMerge.FeildB, AMerge.FeildC, BMerge.FeildD, BMerge.FeildE, BMerge.FeildF, 
FROM 

    (SELECT Id, FieldA, FieldB, FieldC from A1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT Id, FieldA, FieldB, FieldC from A2
    ) AS A
    INNER JOIN 
    (
    SELECT Id, FieldD, FieldE, FieldF FROM B1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT Id, FieldD, FieldE, FieldF FROM B2
    )  AS B

ON A.Id = B.Id
```

where n of A = 8102869, n of B = 17935860, resulting in a table size n=17935860.

How can I refactor this query to be more efficient, or what processes can I perform on the tables or database in order to increase performance for the above query?

Comment: what indexes, statistics you have on that?

Comment: If this is for MySQL please update your question with the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the query plan?

It's possible that making sure there is a clustered index on id on all the tables and refactoring to the following will speed things up. Lots of merge joins in the query and no sorts is probably the best plan you can get out of this.

```
Select
  a1.Id, a1.FieldA, a1.FieldB, a1.FieldC, b1.FieldD, b1.FieldE, b1.FieldF
From 
  A1 Inner Join B1 On A1.ID = B1.ID
Union All
Select
  ...
From
  A2 Inner Join B1 On A2.Id = B1.ID 
Union All 
Select
  ...
From
  A1 Inner Join B2 On A1.Id = B2.ID
Union All
Select
  ...
From
  A2 Inner Join B2 On A2.ID = B2.ID
```

Also, you've tagged this mysql and sql-server. I'm speaking about Sql Server here, don't know enough about the ins and outs of mysql

Comment: Fixed the tag, I'm in the process of setting primary keys for the 4 tables.  First table is taking 15mins+ to add the constraint.  My understanding is that creating the primary key is effectively the same as creating a clustered index on a nun-nullable field.   I will try refactoring.  The query ran for 70 minutes, then I got an "out of disk space error," probably due to lack of space on the local machine.  I will clear space, add the constraints, refactor, and try again.  Do you have a guess for a window in execution time for the given query?

Comment: er no primary key and clustered indexes are not the same at all.

Comment: This says they are.   [Primary Key vs Unique Clustered Index](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/forum/threads/primary-key-vs-unique-clustered-index.24320/).  Maybe you could provide something a little more constructive to add...

Comment: Sorry Sammacow your link does not say that at all http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175132.aspx and a clustered index is not the same as a unique clustered index and I havee said considerably more: see my answer

Comment: @sammarcow clustered indexes permit nulls, and primary keys don't. However, if you create a primary key on a table without a clustered index you'll end up with a unique clustered index too. No guess for the amount of time, it depends on how fast your storage system is.

Comment: @Laurence, can you explain why doing 4 joins and 2 unions would be faster than performing the 2 joins, and 4 unions I have written.. or provide a link?

Comment: @sammarcow Once you get your clustered indexes built, type your query into SQL Management Studio and the hit "Display Estimated Execution Plan". It may well be fine. I was assuming you already had indexes. Then do the same with my query and post up what it says (with pictures if possible)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to have a clustered index on ALL your tables. Without a clustered index your table is a heap and any query will do a table scan - its the only way it can check all the rows.

Second you should have an (complex / muti col) index at least covering any columns you use in any join: ideally with the most granular column first etc.

Thus if you dont have this SQL will mutiply the number of cols in each table together and try to create a temp table of the result.

So if you have 100000 rows in 1 table and 10000 rows in another the calculated row size without indexes will be  1000000000 rows. Heavens know what size temp table that will create!

With indexes (and stats up todate) if the are say 100 rows in one table and 10 rows in another which are likely matches SQL will estimate 1000 rows. Which it can hapilly store in your temp db not to say run a lot faster!

Comment: Ian, are you sure I need to additionally create a clustered index.. looking through your documentation link... "Indexes are automatically created when PRIMARY KEY and UNIQUE constraints are defined on table columns. For example, when you create a table and identify a particular column to be the primary key, the Database Engine automatically creates a PRIMARY KEY constraint and index on that column. For more information, see Creating Indexes (Database Engine)." at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190457(v=sql.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190457(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Well as with all SQL questions, it depends. The ovewhemlming consensus is : you allways need a clustered index, but this can be unique and cover more than one column. Even if its only on one column eg a DATE column (a opposed to datetime) when mutiple entries may have the same date MSSQL will create a Uniquifying entry. The clustered index dictates the order in which row are stored, so if you had an order table DayTaken and DayDelivered you might choose either, or an auto increment identity column. Its good practise not to have the unique index mean anything more than being a row indicator.

Comment: cont.. The clustered index should not need to be rearranged / repacked so in the above example DateTaken would be good but DateDelvered may need to get reorganised on a semi regular basis with rows physically being moved. Because of the way indexes and the stats on those indexes work: the auto increment col will give better insert performance, require less mainenance and give as good a query performance provided the appropriate supporting indexes are present and stats are maintained. Its a big subject and expert people earn lots of money tuning databases for large organisations.